# How to post an images on Google Plus in an iOS Application

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, google-plus

I successfully posted content and (Links)URL using Google Plus API in iphone.
Using Following code:

```
googleShare =[[[GooglePlusShare alloc] initWithClientID:@"my key"] autorelease];


    [googleShare setDelegate:self];
     appDelegate.shareGOOGLe =googleShare;


    NSString *inputURL = @"";
    NSURL *urlToShare = [inputURL length] ? [NSURL URLWithString:inputURL] : nil;

    NSLog(@"%@",urlToShare);
    NSString *inputText = @"TEst Sharing testing from iOS 5.0";
    NSString *text = [inputText length] ? inputText : nil;
      NSLog(@"%@",text);

    [[[[googleShare shareDialog]
       setURLToShare:urlToShare]
      setPrefillText:shareMessge] open];
```

But I want to post images to google plus.

Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have **you** tried?

Comment: what is reason to degrade this question??

Comment: Can you specify what you actually want to do ? I think you haven't surfed on Google properly

Comment: People have things to do during the day and will want to spend their little spare time wisely on the right questions. If you want to post images to Google Plus, look on Google for pointers. If you don't find anything or only partly find your answer, then ask for clarification on StackOverflow. GiveMeTheCodez isn't on.

Comment: @Prypiat what if someone didn't find anything on google and post a question ? i think above question is pretty valid. he needs some guidance not code. Btw Chirag Shah answered the question that has helped me and others.

Answer (score 5):

It is currently not possible to share images on Google+ with the Google+ iOS SDK.

Comment: can you please suggest me how can i share image on google+ by using this method https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share

Answer (score 3):

This is possible to share a Image with google plus

```
- (IBAction) didTapShare: (id)sender {
    id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
    [shareBuilder attachImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImagename.png"]];
    [shareBuilder open];
}
```

Referenced from https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/

Comment: This is deprecated. Do not use.

Answer (score 1):

@Chirag... You should see Flipboard application for iPhone/iPad. It shares the link,comment and Image on Google+ account. Please take a look and let me know if i am wrong at any point.

Comment: see the date he posted the answer. almost an year back.

Answer (score 1):

These are the links will help:

Link Shows how and what can be shared.

1. https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/

at the bottome of link 1, it mentions **"Attaching media to your shared posts. You can attach pictures and movies to your posts for your users to share to their stream."**

2. https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/media

**Link 2 shows the code snippet to share the media ; images and videos**

Following is the Code snippet to share Image on google+

```
- (IBAction) didTapShare: (id)sender {
 id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];

 // Set any prefilled text that you might want to suggest
 [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"Achievement unlocked! I just scored 99 points. Can you beat me?"]

 NSString *fileName = @"samplemedia1";
 [shareBuilder attachImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName];

 [shareBuilder open];
}
```